# How to get base64 string from a data received from fetch in React Native expo app?

Tags: android, react-native, base64, fetch, expo

I'm using fetch in React-Native expo app.

`fetch(url).then( data=>data.blob()).then( data=>`

And here where I got stuck. How to get the Base64 data to use in the data: scheme in the Image component (using URL is not an option) ? It looks like any js base64 converter requires strings, not binary data.

Please advice.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```